# How do I redirect the to index after submitting a new record at the front-end? [Rubymine 2020.2.3, Ruby.2.7.2p137, gem 3.1.2]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubymine

I am struggling with a college project course, and I have been stuck with this error for weeks now, despite the suggestions provided by colleagues and tutors.

In my create method for a given table. I am trying to have the page containing the forms for new record entries redirect back to the index page after saving. Instead, I get redirected to this error instead, highlighting  @courier=Courier.new(courier_new_path) with the error stating that it is not a hash, and would not redirect me back into index. However, when manually searching the index, I see that the data string would indeed get updated.

[I have tried renaming the path label, but Rubymine prompt suggestions appear limited, and any further deviation would cause a different error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14kcl.png)

The following is the create method in the controller page (courier_controller.rb):

```
def create
@courier=Courier.new(params.require(:courier).permit(:courier_name,:courier_email))
@courier.save
redirect_to courier_path(@courier)
@courier=Courier.new(courier_new_path)
if @courier.save
  redirect_to(:controller=>'courier' ,:action=>'index')
else
  render('new')
end 
end
```

Here is the code for the form page (courier/new/html.erb):

```html
<h1>Courier#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/courier/new.html.erb</p>
<%= form_with scope: :courier, :url => {:action => 'create'}, local: true do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :courier_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :courier_name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :courier_email %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :courier_email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I have tried renaming @courier as Courier.new(courier_create_path) or Courier.nww(courier_path), I have tried looking for arguments using a hash form, but none seemed equivocal nor translatable as a solution to my problem.

Any suggestions would help. This is part of a college project, and as a multimedia student not as savvy in programming compared to fellow peers, I would highly appreciate suggestions that I can try out.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has anyone tried to explain what is actually going on in your create method? I've added comments after each line to say what that line is doing.

```
def create
  @courier=Courier.new(params.require(:courier).permit(:courier_name,:courier_email))
# use the params to build a new courier record (the permit part is usually in a separate method that other methods can access but it works this way)
  @courier.save
  # Save the new courier record to the database
  redirect_to courier_path(@courier)
  # Send the user back to the "show" page of the courier record (not index!)
  @courier=Courier.new(courier_new_path)
  # this makes no sense, you are trying to create a new courier object using a path method
  # Basically you are saying: @courier = Courier.new('/courier/new')
  if @courier.save
   #you are trying to save this record that will fail because you can't create a courier by passing it a url
    redirect_to(:controller=>'courier' ,:action=>'index')
     #send the user to the index page of the courier views. 
  else
    render('new')
     #something went wrong so go back to the new courier form.
  end 
end
```

When your program gets to line 4 `redirect_to courier_path(@courier)` it is going to exit the `create` method and send the user to `http://my_app:3000/couriers/1` where the number 1 would be the ID in the database of the record you just created. This would relate to the file in your app in app/views/couriers/show.html.erb. It sounds like you want to get to `http://my_app:3000/couriers` which presents the user with the file app/views/couriers/index.html.erb Not sure why you are doing anything after that line.

Also it is unclear what error you are getting. You need to look at your webserver console, the place where you run "rails s" that shows all the communications between the browser and your app. find the stack trace that starts with the actual error, and add that to your question above (don't paste it in a comment, it will be too long and impossible to read).

I think you just need:

```
def create
  @courier=Courier.new(params.require(:courier).permit(:courier_name,:courier_email))
  if @courier.save
    redirect_to @courier #if you want to redirect to their 'show" page
  else
    render('new')
     #something went wrong so go back to the new courier form.
  end 
end
```

What might be confusing to a new programmer is that Rails is doing so much "magic" behind the scenes it gets very confusing if you don't already know the underlying concepts happening behind the scenes. You are saying `redirect_to(:controller=>'courier' ,:action=>'index')` which specifically says "go to the index page of the couriers" but you can say `redirect_to @courier` and it will assume that you want to go to the page that shows the record of the courier you just created. If you really want to go the table that shows all of the couriers you would replace that with `redirect_to :couriers` The symbol `:couriers` tells it to go to the index method of the couriers controller.

Comment: I forgot to clarify that the index contains the entire list of records for the table. So I have copied your method with the redirect_to remaining the same, in my case, this works. Your suggestions for the @courier also resolved another problem with redirecting to the show page after updating a pre-existing record, which is in accordance to my course requirements.

Considering that I am doing this as part of a college assignment, support from my tutors are limited. Which made me inquire here, instead.

Thank you for your help, it means a lot to me (Y)(Y)